# WireCloud redirect url with proxy

Tags: redirect, proxy, fiware, keystone, fiware-wirecloud

Where can I manually set the `redirect_uri` that is part of the url parameters when clicking on `sign in` in the default WireCloud setup?

We want to show our platform to the internet and need to address our WireCloud server via our proxy. The problem now is, that not the proxy url gets used as redirect url but the internal server url. This leads to the error `{"state": "eCUfYmpXnDV34IVR1P8Vtt2Ke8Xhoxtm", "error": "mismatching_redirect_uri"} (HTTP 400)`.

Comment: By adding `USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = True` to my settings.py the redirect url got better since now the redirect url is the correct server. However the proxy server creates a SSL connection to the client and thus the url should start with https rather than http. But internal the server uses http and no https. So is there a way to change the url to https?
If I change the url manually in the address bar I get a 401 error: Unauthorized for url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following lines into the `settings.py` file:

```
USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = True
USE_X_FORWARDED_PORT = True
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
```

this will configure WireCloud to trust the following headers: `X-Forwarded-Host`, `X-Forwarded-Port` and `X-Forwarded-Proto`. These headers are usually provided by the proxy servers when calling the backend service.

If you prefer to no rely on these headers, you can set the specific values in the `settings.py` file using the following settings instead:

```
FORCE_PROTO = 'https'
FORCE_DOMAIN = 'my.domain.com'
FORCE_PORT = 8000
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast response!