# WireCloud and Horizon behind HTTPS proxy

Tags: proxy, fiware, openstack-horizon, fiware-wirecloud

We have a proxy running that serves HTTPS pages to the internet. Therefore it redirects requests into our DMZ where the pages are served as HTTP pages.

We got WireCloud set up to run at a subdomain: wirecloud.example.com. Horizon runs at horizon.example.com.

In Horizon the Callback URL is set to: http://wirecloud.example.com/complete/fiware/ and in the settings.py of Wirecloud the `FIWARE_IDM_SERVER = 'http://horizon.example.com'` is set.

Now, when `wirecloud.example.com/login` gets called, it is redirected to https by our proxy and then redirected to horizon by wireclound what then gets redirected by our proxy to `https://horizon.example.com/oauth2/authorize/?state=STATE_KEY&redirect_uri=http://wirecloud.example.com/complete/fiware/&response_type=code&client_id=CLIENT_ID`. If the user is not logged in and now does so the redirect_uri gets transformed to this: `http%253A%252F%252Fwirecloud.example.com%252Fcomplete%252Ffiware%252F` what leads to this error: `{"state": "STATE_KEY", "error": "invalid_redirect_uri"} (HTTP 400)`. If the user is already logged in and tries to authorize the app (WireCloud) a 405 error gets thrown:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://wirecloud.example.com/complete/fiware/?state=STATE_KEY&code=CODE

Django Version: 1.9.6
Python Version: 2.7.9
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'wirecloud.commons',
 'compressor',
 'wirecloud.catalogue',
 'wirecloud.platform',
 'wirecloud.oauth2provider',
 'wirecloud.fiware',
 'social.apps.django_app.default')
Installed Middleware:
('wirecloud.commons.middleware.URLMiddleware',)



Traceback:

File "/opt/wc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/opt/wc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/opt/wc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/opt/wc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/opt/wc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/apps/django_app/utils.py" in wrapper
  51.             return func(request, backend, *args, **kwargs)

File "/opt/wc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/apps/django_app/views.py" in complete
  28.                        redirect_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME, *args, **kwargs)

File "/opt/wc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/actions.py" in do_complete
  43.         user = backend.complete(user=user, *args, **kwargs)

File "/opt/wc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/backends/base.py" in complete
  41.         return self.auth_complete(*args, **kwargs)

File "/opt/wc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/utils.py" in wrapper
  229.             return func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/opt/wc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/backends/oauth.py" in auth_complete
  383.             method=self.ACCESS_TOKEN_METHOD

File "/opt/wc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/backends/oauth.py" in request_access_token
  361.         return self.get_json(*args, **kwargs)

File "/opt/wc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/backends/base.py" in get_json
  229.         return self.request(url, *args, **kwargs).json()

File "/opt/wc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/backends/base.py" in request
  225.         response.raise_for_status()

File "/opt/wc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py" in raise_for_status
  844.             raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)

Exception Type: HTTPError at /complete/fiware/
Exception Value: 405 Client Error: METHOD NOT ALLOWED for url: https://horizon.example.com/oauth2/token
```

So how do we need to configure WireCloud and/or Horizon and/or our proxy to get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

Edit your `settings.py` file and add the following lines for forcing WireCloud to use https for the internal urls:

```python
FORCE_PROTO = 'https'
SOCIAL_AUTH_REDIRECT_IS_HTTPS = True
```

This should make WireCloud to use `https://wirecloud.example.com/complete/fiware/` as the `redirect_uri`. See the [`FORCE_PROTO`](https://wirecloud.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation_guide/#force_proto) for more details.

Regarding, this exception:

```
Exception Type: HTTPError at /complete/fiware/
Exception Value: 405 Client Error: METHOD NOT ALLOWED for url: https://horizon.example.com/oauth2/token
```

I need more info for being 100% sure, but seems a problem regarding network visibility. I think that the WireCloud machine is requesting the `https://horizon.example.com/oauth2/token` URL, but this request is not passing through your proxy/frontend server. You can confirm this case, if you have a valid token, by executing the following line from the WireCloud machine and from an external machine:

```
curl -v https://horizon.example.com/oauth2/token?access_token=*****
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast replies!

Together with your suggested changes in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37135806/wirecloud-redirect-url-with-proxy/37167337#37167337 it works much better.

The 405 Error mothod not allowed is no more thrown.

Comment: However: When the user needs to log in, after logging in the url still is transformed and then throws the invalid redicrect uri error. Do you maybe also have a solution to this?

Comment: Please, provide me the full URL with the invalid `redirect_uri` parameter to be able to detect the step where the url gets corrupted. Also check the `Callback URL` field in your KeyRock service contains an URL accessible from the user browser: e.g. `https://wirecloud.example.com/complete/fiware/` (using http**s**)

Comment: `http%253A%252F%252Fwirecloud.example.com%252Fcomplete%252Ffiware%252F` is the invalid redirect uri. Since this url, even if `FORCE_PROTO` is set, always starts with http, the Callback URL in KeyRock is also set to start with http instead of https. I tried it with https but then the missmatching uri error gets thrown.

Comment: ok, the problem is that the `FORCE_PROTO` setting is used only by WireCloud, but the code building the redirect uri comes from `python-social-auth`. Add `SOCIAL_AUTH_REDIRECT_IS_HTTPS = True` into your `settings.py` file.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I now changed the `settings.py` and the initial `redirect_uri` gets displayed correct. But upon logging in the uri gets changed to something that seems to be the correct url but url encoded. Is this an issue with KeyRock, since it takes place in the KeyRock front end?

Comment: sorry, I don't know what say. Could you provide us an example of such encoded url?

Comment: As previously stated, such an example would be `https%253A%252F%252Fwirecloud.example.com%252Fcomplete%252Ffiware%252F`

Comment: yeah, I've tested it and KeyRock encodes the `redirect_uri` parameter, but it should not affect the functionality.

Comment: Well, as long as the URL is encoded the `{"state": "STATE_KEY", "error": "invalid_redirect_uri"} (HTTP 400)` error gets thrown. If I change the `redirect_uri` in the URL bar by hand back to the not encoded version everything runs smooth.